# Selenium Javascript executor returns null

Tags: javascript, selenium, nullpointerexception, selenium-webdriver

I have the following JavaScript code returning `null` when ran through Selenium `JavascriptExecutor`. However, the same code when ran in Firefox developer console returned a value.

```js
function tmp(){
    var attrb = jQuery(jQuery("[name='q']")[0]).attr('type');
    if(typeof attrb !== 'undefined' && attrb !== false){
        return attrb;
    } else {
        return '';
    }
}

tmp();
```

The below is my WebDriver code with the JS the same as above:

```java
JavascriptExecutor jsExec = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
Object inpType = 
       jsExec.executeScript("function tmp(){...}tmp();");
System.out.println("Type: " + inpType);
```

Above outputs `null` instead of "text" string. Any ideas?

Comment: Have added my selenium code above, please have a look.Thanks.

Answer (score 22):

you need to use **return tmp()** instead of **tmp()** in executeScript() method.
Find the related reference
[driver.executeScript() returns NullPointerException for simple javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18520892/driver-executescript-returns-nullpointerexception-for-simple-javascript)

Comment: This works, however then pasting the snippet into browser console, it throws this error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal return statement".

Answer (score 4):

You should add a `return` statement to the result you want to return from inside the `jsExec.executeScript(...)`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you execute two statements in `executeScript()`. The function definition of tmp() and the function call of tmp().

I don't know the details, but the function definition seems to return null.

Since executeScript returns the first value that can be returned, it returns null. If you don't define the function and write the code inline, it will work.

```
JavascriptExecutor jsExec = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
Object inpType = jsExec
    .executeScript("var attrb = jQuery(jQuery(\"[name='q']\")[0]).attr('type');"+
            "if(typeof attrb !== 'undefined' && attrb !== false)" +
            "{return attrb;}" +
            "else{return '';}");
System.out.println("-------------- Type: " + inpType);
```

This should print your expected value.

Edit: Also, your posted code doesn't escape the `""` around `[name='q']`. This ends the string and causes syntax errors.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I do have everything inline earlier, but it caused firefox to return an error which says "return not in a function" which is why i moved this snippet into a function tmp() and called. Coming to quotes, the above is a typo. The script is dynamically generated where i have escaped '"' in my code, for simplicity i copied the above javascript into the function call.

Comment: @Jsm `executeScript()` can have a return statement and does not throw an error. Why not just use the function inline for `executeScript()`, and wrapped in a function for direct entering in Firefox?