# driver.executeScript() returns NullPointerException for simple javascript

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

`js.executeScript("return document.title")` works fine as expected but I'm not sure why my code returns null pointer error. what is wrong here?

```
   String testJs= "function test() {arr = 111; return arr;}; test();";
   JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
   int a = (Integer) js.executeScript(testJS);
```

Comment: What does `js.executeScript()` return? Javadoc clearly says `One of Boolean, Long, String, List or WebElement. Or null.`.

Comment: thats where (last line) its throwing nullpointer error

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This javascript

```
function test() {arr = 111; return arr;}; 
test();
```

Calls the method `test()` but doesn't do anything with the result, ie. doesn't return it to the caller.

So

```
int a = (Integer) js.executeScript(testJS);
```

will return `null` and try to be dereferenced which will fail because dereferencing `null` throws `NullPointerException`.

[Javadoc](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html#executeScript%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) for `JavascriptExecutor.html#executeScript(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object...)`

Maybe you want the javascript

```
function test() {arr = 111; return arr;}; 
return test();
```

This works for me

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\me\\Downloads\\chromedriver.exe");
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
String js = "function test() {" +
            "arr = 111; return arr;" +
            "}; return test()";
Long a = (Long) executor.executeScript(js);
System.out.println(a);
```

Comment: @Sudhakar Did it fail with a `ClassCastException`? Just change the type of your variable. Because it works for me.

Comment: Sorry I was wrong before. Yes your suggestion works perfectly. I had overlooked the important line `One of Boolean, Long, String, List or WebElement. Or null`.
Thank you for your time. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, the key thing is not to forget insert the **return**, f.e.:

```
Long dateNow = (Long) jse.executeScript("return Date.now()");
```

Comment: Yup the missing return was causing it for me