# Getting null pointer exception when I run JavascriptExecutor

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am getting null pointer exception when I try to run JavascriptExecutor. Please find my code below. I have followed the following links from stackoverflow

- [Selenium Javascript executor returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17910632/selenium-javascript-executor-returns-null)

  [driver.executeScript() returns NullPointerException for simple javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18520892/driver-executescript-returns-nullpointerexception-for-simple-javascript)

```html
public void CallApi() {
  try {

   String result = null;
   Thread.sleep(d);
   JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
   String r1 = Uuid(result);
   System.out.println(r1);
   String value = (String) (executor.executeScript("return ContentAPI.getReport('" + r1
     + "').registerOutputType('dataset', function(data) { console.log(data) });"));
   System.out.println(value);
   String js = "function DrillDown() { ContentAPI.getReport('" + r1
     + "').drill('Agency Type', 'Online')}; return DrillDown()";
   long value1 = (long) (executor.executeScript(js));

   System.out.println(value1);

  } catch (InterruptedException e) {

   e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

Please find the error below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJuGL.png)

when I change the value to as per the following I get null returned

String value1 = (String) (executor.executeScript(js));

Comment: is the JS snippet in question pure or does it need any dependent js files like Jquery or something?

Comment: `String js = "function DrillDown() { ContentAPI.getReport('" + r1
     + "').drill('Agency Type', 'Online')}; return DrillDown()";` don't see any return value in this line.

Comment: there is no dependent jquery